# SQL - Joining to Nonexistent Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

After doing a bit of looking, I thought maybe I'd found a solution here: [sql join including null and non existing records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062315/sql-join-including-null-and-non-existing-records#). Cross Joining my tables seems like a great way to solve my problem, but now I've hit a snag:

Below are the tables I’m using:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DCRSales](
    [WorkingDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [Store] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Department] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NetSales] [money] NOT NULL,
    [DSID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stores](
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Has_Deli] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Alcohol_Register] [int] NULL,
    [Is_Cost_Saver] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Store_Status] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Supervisor_Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Email_Address] [nchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Sales_Area] [int] NULL,
    [PZ_Store_Number] [int] NULL,
    [Has_SCO] [bit] NULL,
    [SCO_Reg] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [Has_Ace] [bit] NULL,
    [Ace_Sq_Ft] [int] NULL,
    [Open_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Specialist] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [StateID] [int] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DepartmentMap](
    [Department_Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Parent_Department] [int] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ParentDepartments](
    [Parent_Department] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NULL
```

DCRSales is a table holding new and archived data. The archived data is not perfect, meaning that there are of course certain missing date gaps and some stores which currently have a department they didn't have or no longer have a department they used to have. My goal is to join this table to our department list, list the child departments and parent departments and SUM up the netsales for a given date range. In cases where a store does not have a department whatsoever in that date range, I still need to display it as 0.00.

A more robust solution would probably be to just store all departments for each store regardless of whether they have that department or not (with sales set to 0.00 of course). However I imagine doing that and/or solving my problem here would require very similar queries anyway.

The query I have tried is as follows:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT S.Number as Store, DepartmentMap.Department_Number as Department, ParentDepartments.Parent_Department as Parent, ParentDepartments.Description as ParentDescription, DepartmentMap.Description as ChildDescription
    FROM Stores as S CROSS JOIN dbo.DepartmentMap INNER JOIN ParentDepartments ON DepartmentMap.Parent_Department = ParentDepartments.Parent_Department
    WHERE S.Number IN(<STORES>) AND Department_Number IN(<DEPTS>)
)
SELECT CTE.Store, CTE.Department, SUM(ISNULL(DCRSales.NetSales, 0.00)) as Sales, CTE.Parent, CTE.ParentDescription, CTE.ChildDescription
FROM CTE LEFT JOIN DCRSales ON DCRSales.Department = CTE.Department AND DCRSales.Store = CTE.Store
WHERE DCRSales.WorkingDate BETWEEN '<FIRSTDAY>' AND '<LASTDAY>' OR DCRSales.WorkingDate IS NULL
GROUP BY CTE.Store, CTE.Department, CTE.Parent, CTE.ParentDescription, CTE.ChildDescription
ORDER BY CTE.Store ASC, CTE.Department ASC
```

In this query I try to CROSS JOIN each department to a store from the Stores table so that I can get a combination of every store and every department. I also include the Parent Departments of each department along with the child department's description and the parent department's description. I filter this first portion based on store and department, but this does not change the general concept.

With this result set, I then try to join this table to all of the sales in DCRSales that are within a certain date range. I also include the date if it’s null because the results that have a NULL sales also have a NULL WorkingDate.

This query seemed to work, until I noticed that not all departments are being used with all stores. The stores in particular that do not get combined with all departments are the ones that have no data for the given date range (meaning they have been closed). If there is no data for the department, it should still be listed with its department number, parent number, department description and parent description (with Sales as 0.00). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue, is your `cte` not producing the comprehensive list of stores/departments that you're after? Because the query looks solid.

Comment: The Stores contained in the Stores table are all there and it correctly pulls them all back, however, stores that have no data for the given date range just have a random assortment of the departments with $0.00. I thought the query was pretty solid as well until I noticed that little oddity.

Comment: Oh, your `WHERE` clause is filtering them out, move `DCRSales.WorkingDate BETWEEN '<FIRSTDAY>' AND '<LASTDAY>'` to your join criteria and get rid of `WHERE`

Comment: That was it! Please post your comment as an answer so that I may mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is filtering out records that do have sales at some point in time, but not for the desired period of time, those records don't meet either criteria and are therefore excluded.

I might be under-thinking it, but might just need to move:

```
DCRSales.WorkingDate BETWEEN '<FIRSTDAY>' AND '<LASTDAY>'
```

To your `LEFT JOIN` criteria and get rid of `WHERE` clause. If that's not right, you could filter sales by date in a 2nd cte prior to the join.

Comment: This definitely worked! Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an OUTER JOIN.

See this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Yes, a left- or right- outer-join would be important in extracting records that do not have a counterpart in some other table, but *(in reference to my subsequent answer offered above)* I think that in this actual situation the OP will find that "there is much more to be done, thereafter."

Comment: Upon further inspection, LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are the same thing, the former of which I already use in the query mentioned. A FULL OUTER JOIN also does not produce the correct results. A RIGHT JOIN will, to my knowledge, only include those stores which match. I already know that every store in DCRSales will be matched to one of CTE's departments, meaning that it would essentially be the same as INNER JOIN'ing the two.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that this process is probably *much* too complicated to be done using a single query. I think that you need to perform several queries: to extract the transactions-of-interest into a separate table, then to modify the results one-or-more times in that table before using it to produce your final statistics. A stored procedure, which drives several separately stored queries, could be used to drive the process, which, in several "stages," makes several "passes" over the initially-extracted data.

One piece of important information, for instance, would be to know *when* a particular store had a particular department. (For instance: `store, department, starting_date, ending_date`.) This would be a refinement of a possibly-existing table *(and, maybe, drawn from it ...)* which lists what departments a particular store has *today.*

Let us hope that department-numbers do not *change,* or that your company hasn't acquired other companies with the resulting need to "re-map" these numbers in some way.

Also: frankly, if you have access to a really-good *statistics* package, such as SAS® or SPSS® ... *can "R" do this sort of thing?* ... you might find yourself better-off. (And no, I don't mean "Microsoft Excel ...") **;-)**

When I have been faced with requirements like these *(and I have been, many times ...)*, a stats-package was indispensable. I found that I had to "massage" the process and the extracted data a number of times, in a system of successive-refinement that gradually lead me to a reporting process that I could trust and therefore defend.

Comment: This is definitely an interesting solution. However, we do not use a statistics package (although I'm trying to convince them to use R for more data-oriented stuff), higher ups want it NOW, and I was lucky just to scrape together the data they had into its current format. Where I work, not much thought or time is given to these sorts of things, sadly.

Comment: Perhaps, then, you can use a stored procedure, or a short program/script, to sufficiently emulate the process. Basically: to extract into temporary tables, to manipulate those tables in a series of ways *(without affecting the original data),* and to produce the final results from these. Good luck.